# Force windows to write data through to the disk

Tags: c, windows, windows-xp

I am programming win32 using `fopen` `fread` `fwrite` in C.

How can I force windows to write data through to the disk? Is than an API call for this?

I have a program that must absolutely make sure that data is saved to disk before it saves to a different indexing file, otherwise if there are crashes the index file can sometimes update but the other file doesn't causing a bad inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fflush() does what you want. If you decide to use the Win32 APIs to do your file IO instead of the C STDIO lib, then supply the FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flag to CreateFile(), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fflush.html) function after each fwrite

Answer (score 0):

See the [_commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685(VS.80).aspx) function. Also at [this other MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246717(VS.60).aspx). This only works with _open and other functions, so see [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505) - you can link your program with `commode.obj` to cause `fflush` to commit to the disk.

Comment: I still giggle whenever I see that object filename.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that whatever function you use this will not save you against a power outage or hard reset. Hard disks play smart and can report that write has been finished even if they have just put the data into cache and have not actually written it onto surface.

Answer (score 0):

See [this archived KB article.](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/)

When you initially open your file using fopen, include the "c" mode option as the LAST OPTION:

```
fopen( path, "wc") // w - write mode, c - allow immediate commit to disk
```

Then when you want to force a flush to disk, call

```
_flushall()
```

We made this call before calling

```
fclose()
```

The issue of writes not being persisted to disk caused us real problems, until we discovered this method.

From that above site:

*"Microsoft C/C++ version 7.0 introduces the "c" mode option for the fopen()
function. When an application opens a file and specifies the "c" mode, the
run-time library writes the contents of the file buffer to disk when the
application calls the fflush() or _flushall() function. "*